# xcode build error: Unknown type name 'rootViewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?

Tags: xcode, react-native

Here's my code, Anyone had this issue before

[image: Here's my code, Anyone had this issue before]

Comment: where you is your code?

Comment: i have attached the screenshot of the code where its erroring in AppDelegate.m

Comment: It seem you didn't declare variable **rootViewController**.

Comment: You call variable rootViewController above it declaration (UIViewController * rootViewController = [UIViewController new];)